# Flutter Exception while using file picker package

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Iam using these all packages to my flutter project

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  upi_pay: ^0.2.4  
  google_fonts: ^1.1.0
  file_picker: ^2.0.3
  image_picker: ^0.6.0+9  
  qr_code_scanner: ^0.0.13
  image_gallery_saver: ^1.5.0
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.1
  flutter_barcode_scanner: ^1.0.1
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.6
  google_map_location_picker: ^3.3.5
  flutter_local_notifications: ^1.4.4+1
```

While using this i got such an exception

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@76fc0a16' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > File 'com.android.builder.files.ZipCentralDirectory@2670b2c8' was deleted, but previous version not found in cache

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================
```

If I removed `file_picker: ^2.0.3` & `flutter_full_pdf_viewer: ^1.0.6` from this project, I didn't get any of the exception. In same case if use this both packages(only) in new project no such exception is coming.

Please give a solution for this issue. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

`flutter upgrade` resolves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have added file_picker 4.5.1.  Below steps solved my issue

upgrade gradle version at build/gradle classpath

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
```

upgrade distributionUrl at android>gradle>gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

Finally Invalidate caches and restart studio

You can also delete .gradle under Android folder.